# How to use ActiveDirectory module (RSAT tools) in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

I want to use specific command that are provided by the **"Active Directory Administration with Windows PowerShell"**. So I installed this module on my server.

Now, I want to use these commands in my code. My project is in c# - ASP.NET.

Here's the code I use to call traditional "cmdlet" command (New-Mailbox, Set-User, ...) :

```
string runasUsername = @"Mario";
string runasPassword = "MarioKart";
SecureString ssRunasPassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char x in runasPassword)
    ssRunasPassword.AppendChar(x);
PSCredential credentials =
new PSCredential(runasUsername, ssRunasPassword);

// Prepare the connection
var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("MarioServer"),
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",credentials);
connInfo.AuthenticationMechanism =
            AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
connInfo.SkipCACheck = true;

connInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

// Create the runspace where the command will be executed
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo);

//Params
....

// create the PowerShell command
var command = new Command("New-Mailbox");
command.Parameters.Add("Name", name);
....

// Add the command to the runspace's pipeline
runspace.Open();
var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

// Execute the command
var results = pipeline.Invoke();

if (results.Count > 0)
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
else
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FAIL");

runspace.Dispose();
```

This code work perfectly ! Great ! But let say I want to use **"Set-ADUser"**, this command is from **ActiveDirectory module (RSAT tools)**.

Given that all is set on the server (the module is installed), I tried to simply change "New-Mailbox" for "Set-ADUser" :

```
var command = new Command("Set-ADUser");
```

When I run the code, I have this error :

*The term 'Set-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*

So, that's my question :

How can we run command from the ActiveDirectory module (RSAT tools) in c# ? (Im using VS 2010).

Comment: You should import the Active-Directory module `"import-Module 'Active-Directory'"`

Comment: Can you explain more how to do this ? Thank you

Comment: Set-ADUser is a CmdLet comming from a PowerShell module called "Active Directory". On PowerShell 2.0 You must load Active Directory module before using this CmdLet. Begining PowerShell 3.0 the Module is dynamicaly loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JPBlanc pointed out in the comments section, you will need to ensure that the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module is loaded. PowerShell version 3.0 and later have module auto-loading enabled by default (it can be disabled), but if you're still targeting PowerShell 2.0, then you must first call:

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory;
```

.. before you can use the commands inside the module.

For the purposes of validation, you can use the `Get-Module` command, to ensure that the `ActiveDirectory` module has been imported.

```
Get-Module -Name ActiveDirectory;
```

If the above command returns `$null`, then the module is not imported. To verify that PowerShell can "see" the `ActiveDirectory` module, without actually importing it, run this command:

```
Get-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -ListAvailable;
```

Comment: Another lead whould be to have a look to the project target 32/64bits. Not sure that the Active-Directory Module can load in a 32 bit target EXE file. Specialy installing RSAT tools.

Comment: I tested loading it into 32-bit PowerShell, and it seemed to work on 2012 R2.